# Related to Get service call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

*I just created a HTTP get request to get the content (All the Badges) from Stack Overflow for my console application as shown below* **:**

```
  public void getStackBadges()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.stackexchange.com/docs//badges?order=desc&sort=rank&site=stackoverflow");
            var res = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress).Result;
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
```

*Can anybody please tell if I want to get all the badges from stack overflow using this API what I need to do. I don't really understand the format of result that I am getting on my Cmd prmt !*

***Output on Console:***

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Thu, 28 Dec 2017 09:49:33 GMT
  Content-Length: 880
  Content-Encoding: gzip
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're querying the documentation of the API and you're most likely getting the page markup.

You should be querying: `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/badges?order=desc&sort=rank&site=stackoverflow`

The format of the output in above API method is **JSON**.

Few things to note in the output:

- quota_max - Tells you how many requests can be made by you in a day.
- quota_remaining - How many requests more you can make today.
- has_more - If there is another page with badges.

To change the page you append a `&page=` parameter to the url.

So your query for page 2 would look like this:

`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/badges?page=2&order=desc&sort=rank&site=stackoverflow`

Edit:

As I said, the API I have linked is correct, your problem is the way you try to display the content of the response from the API.

`.Result` is not what you think it is. `.Result` returns `Task<TResult>` which is not the response from the API but the result of the request. That's why you have status code of the request, response type, etc etc.

Here's how to retrieve the response text. This is a sample, you'll need to do your own processing if you want to access different properties of the response objects. This is a separate question though and it's outside the scope of this one.

```
var response =  client.GetAsync("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/badges?order=desc&sort=rank&site=stackoverflow").Result;
string res = "";
using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
{
   Task<string> result =  content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   res = result.Result;
}
```

Comment: i tried as u said still getting same output. I just need to get the batches names.

Comment: @SandeepPandey You're accessing the result of the call wrong. What you access is not what you want. Read the documentation of what you're calling. See my edit for example.

Comment: But i am just calling the  getStackBadges() method nothing else and tried both the URls ,still getting same issue

Comment: @SandeepPandey Like I said above. You're accessing the wrong property of what you want. See my answer again, at the bottom I have explained to you what you're doing wrong, also read the documentation of what you're accessing if you're not getting the desired output, it'll explain why.

Comment: and on the top of it why do need to  use task and async. I want it to be sync call